CGAL after ARAP_parameterizer_3 gets the UVmaps which has the rotation angles ?Texture can map UV
The 2D coordinates of CGAL parameterized by ARAP have rotation angles that are not fixed, resulting in inconsistent texture mapping results later on. How should I solve this problem
SMP::Error_code err = SMP::parameterize(
sm,
SMP::ARAP_parameterizer_3<CommonParameter::SurfaceMesh, Parameterizer>(
Parameterizer(),
CGAL::Eigen_solver_traitsEigen::SparseLU<CGAL::Eigen_sparse_matrix<double::EigenType> >(),
500,
10,
0.1),
bhd,
uvMap);
I hope that regardless of the shape of the model, the parameterized result of UV will be a unified angle, parallel to the X or Y axis. Perhaps I don't have a deep understanding of the principle
